# How to get MongoDB to return numeric array rather than array of dictionary items when returning array of one field from array of documents?

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

Each document in my collection has an array of documents, and each document in that array contains a field named "sport". I'd like to just return an array contained the value of sport for each member of the array. Right now I get an array of dictionaries when I execute this command

```
c = db.users.aggregate([{'$project':{"id_nm":True, "activityArray.sport":True, "lengthArray":{'$size':"$activityArray"}}}])
```

In particular this is the output:

```
                                      activityArray      id_num  lengthArray
0  [{u'sport': 24}, {u'sport': 18}, {u'sport': 24...  21692            4
1  [{u'sport': 2}, {u'sport': 2}, {u'sport': 2}, ...  17990           10
2  [{u'sport': 0}, {u'sport': 0}, {u'sport': 0}, ...  21929            4
3                     [{u'sport': 0}, {u'sport': 0}]  21441            2
4                   [{u'sport': 18}, {u'sport': 18}]  20251            2
```

Is there a way to get just a numeric array returned instead so I don't have to parse each of these rows after putting them into the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required output with:

```
 db.users.aggregate([{$unwind: "$activityArray"},{$group: {_id: "$id_nm", activities: {$push: "$activityArray.sport"}}}, {$project: {"_id": 1, "activities":1, "lengthArray": {'$size': "$activities"}}}]);
```

Or even better:

```
db.users.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$id_nm", activities: {$addToSet: "$activityArray.sport"}, count: {$sum: {$size: "$activityArray"}}}}]);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I want to maintain separate arrays for each user and I also want to maintain a count of how often a number is in an array, so set doesn't work here.

Comment: The 1st usage mentioned above (with $push), should help you achieve that as in `db.users.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$id_nm", activities: {$push: "$activityArray.sport"}, count: {$sum: {$size: "$activityArray"}}}}]);`. Are you expecting something else ?

Comment: the first usage returns one giant array instead of a different array for each user.

Comment: did you try the one i posted with my above comment ? Let us know if that is what you are looking for or if something different.

Comment: The line in the comments is giving this error:  "errmsg" : "exception: The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: EOO", I'm still trying to trouble shoot it. Will let you know if it works.